# JQM multi templete in a page refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-refresh

I have multi templete in a html page.

this is my code

```
<a href="#page1">page1</a>
<a href="#page2">page2</a>
<a href="#page3">page2</a>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  ****collapsible list**** 
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
</div>
```

My problem is when I open(expand) collapsible list on `page1`, move to `page2` and then go back to `page1`, the collapsible list is still open.

How do I fix it ? I mean, do I have to refresh each page(ID) when I click each menu item? How do I do that ?

Please help me, this problem is driving me crazy.

Comment: create a jQuery function that closes all expanded lists and call it on clicking each menu item.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Oma / I'm using JQM v1.4.2